# google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow, object-detection-api, raspberry-pi4

I am building project on detection of floating garbage in water using raspberrypi4b. My model was trained on faster_rcnn. I am using tensorflow version 1.14. I followed https://github.com/EdjeElectronics/TensorFlow-Object-Detection-on-the-Raspberry-Pi this tutorial.This is my code.

```
import os
import cv2
import numpy as np
from picamera.array import PiRGBArray
from picamera import PiCamera
import tensorflow as tf
import argparse
import sys

# Set up camera constants
IM_WIDTH = 1280
IM_HEIGHT = 720
#IM_WIDTH = 640    Use smaller resolution for
#IM_HEIGHT = 480   slightly faster framerate

# Select camera type (if user enters --usbcam when calling this script,
# a USB webcam will be used)
camera_type = 'picamera'
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--usbcam', help='Use a USB webcam instead of picamera',
                action='store_true')
args = parser.parse_args()
if args.usbcam:
    camera_type = 'usb'

# This is needed since the working directory is the object_detection folder.
sys.path.append('..')

# Import utilites
from utils import label_map_util
from utils import visualization_utils as vis_util

# Name of the directory containing the object detection module we're using
MODEL_NAME = 'litter'

# Grab path to current working directory
CWD_PATH = os.getcwd()

# Path to frozen detection graph .pb file, which contains the model that is used
# for object detection.
PATH_TO_CKPT = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'frozen_inference_graph.pb')

# Path to label map file
PATH_TO_LABELS = os.path.join(CWD_PATH,MODEL_NAME,'label_map.pbtxt')

# Number of classes the object detector can identify
NUM_CLASSES = 1

## Load the label map.
# Label maps map indices to category names, so that when the convolution
# network predicts `5`, we know that this corresponds to `airplane`.
# Here we use internal utility functions, but anything that returns a
# dictionary mapping integers to appropriate string labels would be fine
label_map = label_map_util.load_labelmap(PATH_TO_LABELS)
categories = label_map_util.convert_label_map_to_categories(label_map, max_num_classes=NUM_CLASSES, 
use_display_name=True)
category_index = label_map_util.create_category_index(categories)

# Load the Tensorflow model into memory.
detection_graph = tf.Graph()
with detection_graph.as_default():
od_graph_def = tf.GraphDef()
with tf.gfile.GFile(PATH_TO_CKPT, 'rb') as fid:
    serialized_graph = fid.read()
    od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
    tf.import_graph_def(od_graph_def, name='')

sess = tf.Session(graph=detection_graph)


# Define input and output tensors (i.e. data) for the object detection classifier

# Input tensor is the image
image_tensor = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('image_tensor:0')

# Output tensors are the detection boxes, scores, and classes
# Each box represents a part of the image where a particular object was detected
detection_boxes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_boxes:0')

# Each score represents level of confidence for each of the objects.
# The score is shown on the result image, together with the class label.
detection_scores = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_scores:0')
detection_classes = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('detection_classes:0')

# Number of objects detected
num_detections = detection_graph.get_tensor_by_name('num_detections:0')

# Initialize frame rate calculation
frame_rate_calc = 1
freq = cv2.getTickFrequency()
font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX

# Initialize camera and perform object detection.
# The camera has to be set up and used differently depending on if it's a
# Picamera or USB webcam.

# I know this is ugly, but I basically copy+pasted the code for the object
# detection loop twice, and made one work for Picamera and the other work
# for USB.

### Picamera ###
if camera_type == 'picamera':
# Initialize Picamera and grab reference to the raw capture
camera = PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT)
camera.framerate = 10
rawCapture = PiRGBArray(camera, size=(IM_WIDTH,IM_HEIGHT))
rawCapture.truncate(0)

for frame1 in camera.capture_continuous(rawCapture, format="bgr",use_video_port=True):

    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    frame = np.copy(frame1.array)
    frame.setflags(write=1)
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.40)

    cv2.putText(frame,"FPS: {0:.2f}".format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),font,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (t2-t1)/freq
    frame_rate_calc = 1/time1

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

    rawCapture.truncate(0)

camera.close()

### USB webcam ###
elif camera_type == 'usb':
    # Initialize USB webcam feed
    camera = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
    ret = camera.set(3,IM_WIDTH)
    ret = camera.set(4,IM_HEIGHT)

while(True):

    t1 = cv2.getTickCount()

    # Acquire frame and expand frame dimensions to have shape: [1, None, None, 3]
    # i.e. a single-column array, where each item in the column has the pixel RGB value
    ret, frame = camera.read()
    frame_rgb = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    frame_expanded = np.expand_dims(frame_rgb, axis=0)

    # Perform the actual detection by running the model with the image as input
    (boxes, scores, classes, num) = sess.run(
        [detection_boxes, detection_scores, detection_classes, num_detections],
        feed_dict={image_tensor: frame_expanded})

    # Draw the results of the detection (aka 'visulaize the results')
    vis_util.visualize_boxes_and_labels_on_image_array(
        frame,
        np.squeeze(boxes),
        np.squeeze(classes).astype(np.int32),
        np.squeeze(scores),
        category_index,
        use_normalized_coordinates=True,
        line_thickness=8,
        min_score_thresh=0.85)

    cv2.putText(frame,"FPS: {0:.2f}".format(frame_rate_calc),(30,50),font,1,(255,255,0),2,cv2.LINE_AA)

    # All the results have been drawn on the frame, so it's time to display it.
    cv2.imshow('Object detector', frame)

    t2 = cv2.getTickCount()
    time1 = (t2-t1)/freq
    frame_rate_calc = 1/time1

    # Press 'q' to quit
    if cv2.waitKey(1) == ord('q'):
        break

camera.release()

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

This is the error I am getting:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "litter.py", line 85, in <module>
od_graph_def.ParseFromString(serialized_graph)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/message.py", line 187, in 
ParseFromString
return self.MergeFromString(serialized)
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 
1127, in MergeFromString
if self._InternalParse(serialized, 0, length) != length:
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/python_message.py", line 
1181, in InternalParse
buffer, new_pos, wire_type)  # pylint: disable=protected-access
File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/google/protobuf/internal/decoder.py", line 973, in 
_DecodeUnknownField
raise _DecodeError('Wrong wire type in tag.')
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Wrong wire type in tag.
```

Comment: I have the same issue, did you manage to solve this ?